# Mongoose Mongodb querying an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to get what I expect to see when querying an array using Mongoose. A user can have many rooms associated with his/her account. The room objects are stored in an array attached to the user within the collection. There is only one collection called users.

Consider the following two Schemas for user and room:

USER SCHEMA

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local            : {
    username     : String,
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
    rooms        : {type:Array, default: []}
}  


});
```

ROOM SCHEMA

```
var roomSchema = mongoose.Schema({

     name: String

});
```

This is the query I have tried:

```
var User = require('../models/user');

User.find({ 'rooms.name' : req.body.username  }, 
            { rooms: 
                { $elemMatch : 
                   { 
                     name: req.body.username 
                   } 
                } 
            }, function (err, user) {

        if (err){
            return done(err);
        }    

        console.log("user:::", user);

        if (user) {
            console.log("ROOM NAME FOUND");
            req.roomNameAlreadyInUse = true;
            next();

        } else {
            req.roomNameAlreadyInUse = false;
            console.log("ROOM NAME NOT FOUND");
            next();

        }

    });
```

The problem is this query seems to always return an empty array even if it should contiain something or if it should return nothing. So how would I search through all users room arrays to see if the room name already exists?

I have also tried the following to queries but neither are successful:

```
User.find({local: {rooms: {$elemMatch: {name: req.body.username}}}}, function (err,     user) {

}



User.find({'local.rooms': {$elemMatch: {name: req.body.username}}}, function (err, user) {

}
```

I should also point out that the database is populated as I can see the array (which has 1 element created on user account creation) in robomongo.

Sample data from console output to show database is being populated (including user.rooms array):

> db.users.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("533c4db2b2c311a81be8a256"), "local" : { "password" : "$2a$08$0yQQJ2y0726kZtkWY5mAPOgZhacOmZn0Fd8DlausiuMB
>   XE4ZblTXS", "username" : "paul", "email" : "test", "rooms" : [  {  "name" : "paul",  "*id" : ObjectId("533c4db2b2c311a81be8a2
>   57") } ], "status" : "active" }, "*_v" : 0 }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("533c4ddab2c311a81be8a258"), "local" : { "password" : "$2a$08$dC3CbDTkG5ozECDTu/IicO3Az0WdkzlGh2xDcb8j1CF/
>   FQhe5guZq", "username" : "john", "email" : "test2", "rooms" : [  {  "name" : "john",  "*id" : ObjectId("533c4ddab2c311a81be8a
>   259") } ], "status" : "active" }, "*_v" : 0 }

Comment: What does the data actually look like in your "users" collection from the mongo shell? I also see some problems with your schema definition and you do not make it clear if the data is in one collection or two. You could add this to your question.

Comment: What problems do you see with my Schema Neil Lunn? The data is all in a single collection.

Comment: The other questions were more important, so it would help if you can edit. What I was referring to here though was that "roomSchema" appears not to be used. It would normally be referenced in "userSchema". But the most important thing we need to see is some of your data.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, I have added some more info. I also changed the find call to findOne which now works (see my answer below.) The roomSchema is used when a user creates their account. I did try to add the rooms schema inside the users schema array something like this - room: [roomSchema]. But I couldn't get this to work. It kind of makes sense to me how I am doing it now i.e. when a user creates their account a user model and a room model are created and the room model is then inserted into the user model. I am not sure if this is the best way or if it against best practice but it seems to work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I changed it to use findOne instead of find and it works now. I am not too sure why this should make a difference. This is the findOne function I used:

```
User.findOne({'local.rooms': {$elemMatch: {name: req.body.username}}}, function (err, user) {

        if (err){
            return done(err);
        }    

        if (user) {
            console.log("ROOM NAME FOUND");
            req.roomNameAlreadyInUse = true;
            next();

        } else {
            req.roomNameAlreadyInUse = false;
            console.log("ROOM NAME NOT FOUND");
            next();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 6):

`findOne` returns a single document, where `find` returns a cursor. Once you go through the cursor of find, you are at the end, and there are no more documents.

```
User.findOne({'local.rooms': {$elemMatch: {name: req.body.username}}}, (err,UserInfo) => {

        if (err){
            return res.status(400).json({Error:"Something went wrong please try again"})
        }    

        if (UserInfo) {
            console.log("ROOM NAME FOUND");
            req.roomNameAlreadyInUse = true;
            res.json({msg:"Room name found.",userData:UserInfo})

        } else {
            req.roomNameAlreadyInUse = false;
            console.log("ROOM NAME NOT FOUND");
            res.json({msg:"Room name not found."})
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler. And I tend to use async functions and the following code does that more cleanly. Make sure you index by your array if you do this a lot (it can be slow).

```
let users = await User.find({'rooms.name':req.body.username);
console.log(users);
```