# findOne mongoose query is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I have used express to create this web-app.
I also have mongoose model:

```
{
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  notes: [{
    name: { type: String, required: true }
  }]
}
```

When I try to find object inside of array(Notes) ->

```
modelName.findOne({ "notes:" {$elemMatch: {"_id": req.body.id } }})
  .exec()
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I get whole model object of one user instead of one note.
Here is the result which I get:

```
{
  "_id": "5c51dd8be279e9016716e5b9",
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "",
  "notes": [
    {
      "_id": "5c51dd8be279e901671gagag",
      "name": "name of note1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c51ff8be279e901671gagag",
      "name": "name of note"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c51dd8be2131501671gagag",
      "name": "name of note"
    }
  ]
}
```

My expectation, however, is to receive something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5c51dd8be279e901671gagag",
  "name": "name of note1"
}
```

P.S: It is not duplicate of this answer [Mongoose Mongodb querying an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806326/mongoose-mongodb-querying-an-array-of-objects). I have already tried to use code from that question, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Mongodb querying an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806326/mongoose-mongodb-querying-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findOne() is working just fine. findOne() returns any document that matches the specified query, not part of a document. If you want just part of that document, you will have to get it in two parts...

```
modelName.findOne({ "notes": {$elemMatch: {"_id": req.body.id } }})
.exec()
.then(result => {
  // Will get an array of notes whose _id === req.body.id
  const resNote = result.notes.filter(n => n._id === req.body.id);
  console.log(resNote);
})
.catch(err => {
console.log(err);
});
```

See the documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne). If you note, it mentions that the function " finds one document".

Comment: It has to be"notes":  not "notes:". I tried it and I got CoreMongooseArray []

Comment: Do you mean it has to be CoreMongooseArray? Or do you mean something like "It is interesting issue". I am not native speaker, sorry for stupid question)

Comment: It should be "notes":    Try the above code, **result** should be a single document. **resNote** should be an array of the objects that you desire.

Comment: Omg, it finally worked. Your answer is correct, but because of triple '===' in filter method, I was receiving empty array.  I changed it to double '==' and it works. Thanks))

Comment: Glad to hear!! If you want to use the === (which is safer than ==), you should be able to write the filter call with a .toString(), like this: `result.notes.filter(n => n._id.toString() === req.body.id);`

Comment: Thanks for that too) I have been using postman to make api requests and I have been writing id as a String, but mongoDB returns id as Integer. It was the reason why it didn't work properly

Answer (score 1):

you can use this instead

```
// Select only the modelName name and _id
modelName.findOne({ "notes:" {$elemMatch: {"_id": req.body.id } }}, '_id name').exec().  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
output: {
  "_id": "5c51dd8be279e901671gagag",
  "name": "name of note1"
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35445027)