# How to create a Post Request for Express/Mongoose Normalized Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: node.js, express, post, mongoose, router

I am trying to learn how to create a Normalized many to many Post request in express/router and Mongoose.

I have three collections: User, Building and Room which is also the order of parent to child documents.

My Building document schema includes both User and Room id's as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const BuildingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 user: [
   {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "user"
   }
 ],
 room: [
   {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "room"
   }
 ],
```

My Room document schema includes the Building ID and another child document as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  building: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "building"
    },
  furniture: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "furniture"
    }
  ],
```

I am having trouble understanding how to create a post request that allows a user/users to create a Building instance and multiple Room instances associated with it after...

My express code so far can create a new Building instance but I am unsure how to handle including the Room id's:

```
router.post('/createbuilding', [auth, [
  check('name', 'Building Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
 ]
], async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
        
    const {
      name,
      type,
      website,
      location,
      bio,      
    } = req.body;

    const buildingFields = {
      user: req.user.id,
      //room: req.room.id,
      name,
      type,
      website: website && website !== '' ? normalize(website, { forceHttps: true }) : '',
      location,
      bio
    };

      try {
        let building = await Building.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          //{ room: req.room.id },
          { $set: buildingFields },
          { new: true, upsert: true }
        );
        res.json(building);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
      }
    }
  );
```

Note: The references to room ID are commented out on purpose because this is what I am unsure of how to include in the Post request.

Answer (score 0):

With Mongoose's `.findOneAndUpdate()` the first parameter is to query for the document, similar to `.findOne()`. Your second parameter is what fields to update. `$set` is redundant since Mongoose will do that for you.

If you want to add a room to the building rather than replacing all the associations, you'll want to add the room with a `$push`.

```js
const buildingFields = {
  $push: {
    room: {
      req.room.id
    }
  },
  name,
  type,
  ...
}
```

I am also assuming that you intended that the user field in BuildingSchema is a single association rather than a many associations. If not, you'd need to use a `$elemMatch` to query for that document:

[Mongoose Mongodb querying an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806326/mongoose-mongodb-querying-an-array-of-objects)